# How do I check if the data entered in the login form text box is alphanumeric using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium

I recently migrated from Selenium RC to Web driver. I am testing a registration form which contains "login" field. I have to test the form based on 2 criteria:

1. The name entered in the Login field should not be used by any other user.
2. The Login name field is alpha numeric and should be minimum 4 character in length.How can I test if a user enters a login name which is at least 4 characters in length and is a combination of alphabets and numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [Getting Started with Selenium](http://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium) framework...

This would account for #2 and #3...

your test would look like,

```
@Config(url="http://myurl.com")
public class MyTestClass extends AutomationTest {

  @Test
  public void testInput() {
    setText(By.id('myInput'), "my test");
    String b = getText(By.id('myInput'));
    assertTrue(b.matches('[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,}'));
  }
}
```

As far as #1 goes.. run through your scenario manually, then pull your selector, then just...

```
validatePresent(By.cssSelector("div.errorMsg"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex. Grab the login name and see if it matches `[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,}`.